# Why can't I extend this partition?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning

My system hard drive on my Windows computer is partitioned into 3 primary partitions, and 200+GB additional free space.  The partitions are contiguous:

```
   C:   20GB
   D:   25GB
   E:  208GB
free:  212GB
```

I'd like to expand the `E:` partition, but in the Windows Disk Management GUI, the `Extend Volume` context-menu option is grayed out and unselectable:

[image]

Why won't Windows let me expand this partition?

Comment: rephrased your question; hopefully this is roughly what you meant...

Comment: Except I'm using Windows 7 RC.

Comment: think i got "vista" off the C: drive label in the screenshot.  thx for correcting. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copied from [Facepunch](http://www.facepunch.com/showpost.php?p=19001450&postcount=4):

> Delete that logical partition
>   containing the free space at the end
>   then you'll be able to extend it.

Comment: Yeah, make it raw unallocated space.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem trying to repartition a Vista machine to make have a big enough single partition for Windows 7.  Was unable to get Vista to do it, even after deleting the other patition on the drive.  Ultimately solved the problem using gparted, as described [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-gparted-to-resize-your-windows-vista-partition/).

Comment: In my experience, linux/open-source tools are usually your best bet for advanced stuff like this.

Answer (score 2):

Try unmounting it first.  RClick, choose 'Change Drive Letter and Path', then remove the existing drive letter.  Then try to extend.

Comment: sounds reasonable.  worth a try.  you can also use the `mountvol` command on the commandline; `mountvol X: /D` will unmount the volume and remove the drive letter.  use `mountvol` or that "Change Drive Letter and Path" dialog to remount it when done (though a reboot might be recommended).