# Partition resizing on dual boot

Tags: windows, ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot

I have to partitions, ntfs and ext3 with windows 7 and ubuntu 11 respectively. They were side by side, first ntfs then ext3. I shrunk and resized the ext3 so that there was space immedeatly after the ntfs. This worked fine using gparted. The problem is that now I am not able to extend the windows partition. Why could this be?

Edit: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I extend this partition?](https://superuser.com/questions/84363/why-cant-i-extend-this-partition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the ext3 partition is a logical drive inside an extended partition and the NTFS one is a primary partition. You've shrunk the logical drive, but not the extended partition. Shrink it too and GParted will let you resize the Windows partition.

Comment: oh ok so i just drag the extended part as well in the gparted gui? I will try and report back thanks.